# When was federal sovereign immunity in the U.S. established?

Tags: united-states, law

Lawsuits against the federal government can be dismissed under the doctrine of sovereign immunity. For example, Al Haramain Islamic Foundation v. Obama was recently dismissed ([Appeals court dismisses warrantless wiretapping suit](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/08/appeals-court-dismisses-warantless-wiretapping-suit/)). The constitution refers to the "immunities of citizens" but not to "sovereign immunity".

Was federal sovereign immunity in place from the beginning? Was it established by a particular court ruling, or was it understood to be in effect (e.g., due to common law precedent)? Has there ever been a significant controversy over federal sovereign immunity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sovereign Immunity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_immunity) was there from the beginning. In fact, the very first constitutional ammendment that was passed after ratification ([the 11th](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)) was designed to tweak it a bit.

It was a principle brought over from [English law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_immunity#United_Kingdom), although it actually applies in many countries around the world, particularly constitutional monarchies.